# How to fix a loop to print lists into individual cells

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a loop to work with a function that prints a list and save the list for each row in a single new column.

I can run the loop, but I end up with only the results list for the last word repeated in every row in the new column.

```
library(vwr)
test = c("cat", "bat", "rat", "tow", "row")
test = data.frame(test)
for (i in test$test){
    test$save[i] = levenshtein.neighbors(i,test$test)[1]}
```

Once the loop runs, I end up with `test$save` as the list of neighbors for "row" ("tow") in *every* cell.

I want each cell in the `test$save` column to have the neighbors for that word (i.e. "cat" should have "bat" and "rat"; "tow" should have "row"). Eventually, this will be with 100,000+ words in a dataset with 50 other columns, so I can't do too much manual work either.

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Comment: Please take a look at what you can and should do to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example); in a nutshell, you should include (1) minimal sample data, (2) reproducible code that we can copy&paste including any non-base R `library` calls (where is `levenshtein.neighbors` from?), and (3) your expected output.

Comment: Thank you!  I have included more code with where levenshtein.neighbors comes from.  I hope this clarifies those issues.

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure what you want to achieve but this code seems to work fine:

```
library(vwr)

test <- list(cat = c("cat", "bat", "rat", "tow", "row"))

for (i in test$cat){
  test$save[i] = levenshtein.neighbors(i,test$cat)[1]
}
test$save
```

In this example, `test$cat` is a vector and not a dataframe. The rest of the code remains unchanged.

Comment: Oh!  Thank you, I think this is very close.  I should clarify that I need test$save to be a single column in a larger dataframe, where each row is dedicated to one word and each column is a word feature.  I can coerce the "word" column into a list, but I'm not sure how to coerce the results of test$save$cat and test$save$bat, etc. into a single column when I have so many words. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Technically a dataframe is just a special case of a list, i.e. a list where every element is a vector of the same length. In your case it seems that it would be better to work with lists as the example yields a varying number of neighbors.